ffmpeg -c:s dvdsub continues processing after writing the outuput
When running
ffmpeg -y -t 20 -i test-in.ts -c:s dvdsub test-out.mp4

ffmpeg continues to use CPU after writing the 20 seconds of output.
Observed with versions 6.1.1 and 7.0.
There is no such problem without -c:s dvdsub.
How could I avoid the processing after finishing the output please?
Here is the output with the -report option once with "-c:s dvdsub" and once without: http://pmrb.free.fr/tmp/ffmpeg/.
TIA for any hints, Peter

Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.

Ok. Here, once with "-c:s dvdsub" and once without: http://pmrb.free.fr/tmp/ffmpeg/

Please [edit] the question and add it, not just in comments

@Gyan The report you asked for is here.
